# Linking to a file (e.g. PDF) within a CakePHP view

Tags: cakephp

I'd like to link to some PDFs in one of my controller views. What's the best practice for accomplishing this? The CakePHP webroot folder contains a ./files/ subfolder, I am confounded by trying to link to it without using "magic" pathnames in my href (e.g. "/path/to/my/webroot/files/myfile.pdf").

What are my options?

**EDIT:** I didn't adequately describe my question. I was attempting to link to files in /app/webroot/files/ in a platform-agnostic (ie. no `mod_rewrite`) way.

I've since worked around this issue by storing such files outside the CakePHP directory structure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$html->link('Pdf', '/files/myfile.pdf');
```

Comment: This is, strictly, the correct answer to my question. However, I didn't communicate well that I was struggling with linking to files in the /app/webroot/files directory across multiple platforms; specifically, where mod_rewrite isn't available...

Comment: i am using this as echo $this->Html->link(substr($result['S']['RESULT'],0,20),$result['S']['filepath']); but it gives <a href="/cityportal_v1.1.1/index.php/var/www/cityportal_v1.1.1/app/webroot/upload/government/docs/a38adebfd60d81b32b9b0f330e213055.pdf">COMPUTER CRIMEA JOIN</a>..i want i as u got

Comment: Make sure it is spelled correctly (path and filename) or else it throws missing controller errors. Gave me headaches for a while...

Answer (score 6):

This is somewhat tangential, but for access to such a location in Models and other places you can simply do this:

```
$file = WWW_ROOT . DS . 'files' . DS;
```

This tactic might be helpful to someone accessing files for static data loading, such as XML or JSON.

This is not recommended for public consumption or public linking.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that this is an issue when mod_rewrite is not being used.

```
<?php echo $html->link('pdf', '/files/test.pdf'); ?>
```

outputs

```
<a href="/pathtoapp/index.php/files/test.pdf">pdf</a>
```

it should output

```
<a href="/pathtoapp/app/webroot/files/test.pdf">pdf</a>
```

Comment: note: bug filed http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1289-htmlhelperlink-to-image-broken-when-not-using-mod_rewrite#ticket-1289-3

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
<?php echo $html->link('pdf', $this->webroot('files'.DS.'test.pdf'); ?>
```

Comment: It works, but on newer versions of CakePHP, `$html->webroot` should be used instead of `$this->webroot`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but here goes. Basically any file you put in the webroot folder will be accessible on the webserver, so if you put the file in webroot/files/file.pdf you would simply link to /files/file.pdf.

If that doesn't work, please clarify your question...

Answer (score 1):

or..

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>files/somefile.pdf">Link Text</a>
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

or...

```
<a href="<?php echo $html->url('/files/somefile.pdf'); ?>">Link Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       <a href="<?php echo $this->request->webroot . 'carpetadentrodelwebroot/archivo.pdf'; ?>" target="pdf-frame" download="nombreParaDescarga">Descargar Archivo</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.