# How do Media Views work in cakephp?

Tags: file-io, cakephp-2.1

I have arranged a file upload to happen on my application relative address: webroot/files

Now I need to force download on the uploaded files. After some googling and trying like most of the suggestions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233643/linking-to-a-file-e-g-pdf-within-a-cakephp-view) I figured out the correct way to do this is using cakephps [Media Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html)

**What I have:**

1. Main site with a table of records. **Model ->** Record; **Table** -> records;
2. These records have a primary key record_id.
3. In my database I have a **Table** -> files; **Model** -> File;
4. These files have a foreign key record_id and a field 'url' with the relative path to it's location.
5. After creating a record with files, the files are correctly uploaded to the folder, which      relative address is e.g. webroot/files/record_name/file and the tables in database are    correctly updated.

**What I want to do:**

1. After doubleclicking on one table row open a modal dialog with the information about the record. (done)
2. In this modal dialog I want to display links that will force download on these files.

**I tried many variations of this:**

```
//the retrieving of data after debug looks fine//
$this->loadModel('File');
$files = $this->File->find('list', array(
    'conditions'=>array('File.record_id'=>$record_id),
    'fields' => array('File.Name', 'File.Url');
))

//actual display of url
foreach($files as $file_name => $file_url) {
    echo $this->Html->link($file_name, $file_url);
}
```

The resulting link looks exactly the way [James Revillini presented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513309/1315125)

**This is my actual question**

Since that issue was not entirely solved, I thought it would be helpful not only for me, but for anybody who's searching for a quick solution for this problem to see a quick demonstration of how [Media-views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html) work. I have no idea where to move after making a dynamic download function:

```
    public function download($name, $path) {
    $this->viewClass = 'Media';
    $params = array(
        'id'        => $name,
        'name'      => $name,
        'download'  => true,
        'path'      => $path
        );
        $this->set($params);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point the link in the modal dialog for the resource to the `download()` function.

Pass the `Record.id` to that function. In it find the file and auto-render it.

It should work.